# Remove duplicates from an unsorted array

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a function to remove duplicates from an unsorted int array. I have a solution that works for more examples, but it's failing with the following input:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
    int j = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){

            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                 n--;
                for (int k=i; k<n; k++){
                    arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    n = removeDuplicates(arr, n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

The output for this arr example is 0 0 1 0 0 and should be 0 1.

Do you see where is the problem? Thank you

Comment: Regardless of bugs in this solution, the main problem I see is that this looks like O(n³) for a problem that can be trivially solved in O(n²).

Comment: @MatteoItalia I think that the problem can be (relatively trivially) solved in _O(n log n)_. There are generally 2 options: 1) _in-place_ based on in-place sorting, where the content of the original array is destroyed, and 2) _out-of-place_, where either array can be copied and then sorted, or a set can be utilized. All these are _O(n log n)_ and can be written with few lines of code.

Comment: @DanielLangr: those are the trivial O(n log n) solutions with O(n) extra storage; what would be more interesting are better-than-O(n²) solutions with O(1) extra storage.

Comment: @MatteoItalia When sorting with quicksort, the overall time complexity is _O(n log n)_ without _O(n)_ extra storage. Though it is not _O(1)_ as well due to stack space required for recursion, which is _O(log n)_ in efficient quicksort implementations.

Comment: @DanielLangr: but, as you said, that destroys the original data ordering, which can be trivially preserved by sorting just a copy (so, O(n) extra space) and then using it for fast (O(log n)) lookup of the elements to remove - like the `std::set` solution below, but generally more efficient due to smaller time constants (`std::set` is a bit of a pig for small elements, as it generally needs a heap allocation for each node, so heap overhead + often bad cache locality).

Comment: @MatteoItalia Agree. It's not clear to me what OP wants to achieve. Since in his attempt, original array contents is destroyed as well. The question is whether the order of output unique elements should match their order in the input unsorted array, such that `{3,0,3,1,1}` should be transformed to `{3,0,1}` (out-of-place) or `{3,0,1,*,*}` (in-place). Then, solution based on sorting and sets would not work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

look over inner loop you forgot to decrement `i`

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
    int j = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){

            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                n--;
                for (int k=i; k<n; k++){
                    arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                }
                i--;     // you forgot to decrement i
            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);

    n = removeDuplicates(arr, n);

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++)
        cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Consider using `std::set<int>` to record numbers you've already seen, and using a STL algorithm to perform the removal:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
#include<set>

// Driver code
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1};
    std::set<int> duplicates;

    auto it = std::remove_if(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), [&duplicates](int i) {
        return !duplicates.insert(i).second;
    });
    size_t n = std::distance(std::begin(arr), it);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i] << " ";

    return 0;
}
```

The effect of this code is that all duplicates are moved to the end of the array, and the iterator returned by `std::remove_if` indicates the end of the new list. So iterating between the beginning and that iterator gives you the array without the duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

In your function

```
int removeDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
    int j = 0;

for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(j=i+1;j<n;)
    {
        if(a[i]==a[j])
        {
            for(int k=j;k<n-1;++k)
                arr[k]=arr[k+1];

            --n;
        }
        else
            ++j;
    }
}

return n;
}
```

Increment j only when the two values do not match. Or else it will skip few values

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

A possible solution that is *O(n log n)* in time and requires *O(m)* extra space, where *m* is the number of unique elements in the input array:

```
template <typename RAIter>
size_t remove_duplicates(RAIter first, RAIter last) {
   using value_type = typename std::iterator_traits<RAIter>::value_type;
   std::map<value_type, size_t> map;
   size_t n = 0;
   for (auto it = first; it != last; ++it) {
      auto & temp = map[*it];
      if (temp == 0) temp = ++n;
   }
   for (auto & e : map)
      *(first + e.second - 1) = e.first;
   return n;
}
```

Note also that the contents of the original array is destroyed here, but this is in your attempt as well.

Possible usage:

```
int main() {
   static constexpr size_t n = 26;
   std::array<int, n> a = { 0, 0, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1 };

   size_t m = remove_duplicates(std::begin(a), std::end(a));
   for (size_t i = 0; i < m; i++)
       std::cout << a[i] << " ";
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Which prints out `0 1 3 2`.

---

I compared my solution with yours (corrected by @Onk_r). For an input array of 500,000 elements having random values from [0,100). My *O(n log n)* solution took **19 milliseconds**, while your *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* solution took **54 seconds**! Nice demonstration of how much complexity matters :).

Comment: but, can you keep the original order of the elements with any of these solutions? (should be 0 1 3 2 in your example)

Comment: @A.Palomo It was not clear from your question that you wanted to achieve this. Then, solutions based on sorting or sets cannot work.

Comment: @A.Palomo I completely rewrote my answer to fulfill your requirements. Note that for large inputs, you really want to avoid _O(n²)_ and _O(n³)_ algorithms at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

It works, but you have to start with `j=1`, not 0

wrong:

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j=0;j<=i;j++)
```

solution:

```
for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
    for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int arr1[] = {3, 1, 5, 4, 5, 1, 9, 3, 9, 7};
int size = sizeof(arr1) / sizeof(arr1[0]);

int i, j, k = 0;
int arr2[size];

for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < k; j++)
    {
        if(arr1[i] == arr2[j])
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    if(j == k)
    {
        arr2[k++] = arr1[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use a set instead since all elements in a set must be unique.  http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/