# Best way to remove non uniques values from an array, keep the order, and not use vectors?

Tags: c++, sorting

I apologize if this has been asked, but I ran into a coding question, which was supposed to be simple but I struggled on. Please provide a link if already answered (I may just be bad at searching).

Question: Given the sample code fill in the function to return only unique values in the array. Values must keep order.

Example Input : 1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 3, 2, 10, 1, 11, 6

Example Output: 1 2 3 10 4 11 6

Below is my solution, but I can not seem to think of an easy solution that does not include the use of a vector to store unique values. The tester did not like the use of a vector so I can only assume additional headers / libraries were unacceptable. Any other solutions? I am guessing the tester was looking for the array to be filtered in place.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> //I was not allowed to add this...

//Function to fill in...
int fxn(int *a, int size)
{
  std::vector<int> temp;
  for(int i(0); i < size; ++i)
  {
    bool found(false);
    for(auto j : temp)
    {
      if( j == a[i])
      {
        found = true;
        break;
      }
    }

    if(!found)
    {
      temp.push_back(a[i]);
    }
  }

  int *ptr_a = &a[0];
  for(auto j : temp)
  {
    *ptr_a = j;
    ++ptr_a;
  }

  return size - temp.size();
}

//The rest untochable...
void print(int *a, int size)
{
  for(int i(0); i < size; ++i)
  {
    std::cout << a[i] << " ";
  }

  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{

  int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 10, 4, 3, 2, 10, 1, 11, 6 };
  int size = 11;

  int count = fxn(a, size);
  print(a, size - count);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: C++ includes all of the standard C++ library.  Is this in an academic setting with arbitrary constraints to teach specific principles and idioms?

Comment: Have two counts. One for the current unique element and one to iterate through the array. Swap the adjacent  values as you iterate up to move the non unique to the end. Or honestly just call std::unique which does the same thing probably.

Comment: one in place solution is to keep a `write` pointer and a `read` pointer. They both start at the beginning of the array, and you only write the values under `read` that are not before the `write` pointer. With this problem you have an invariant that `read>=write`

Comment: You can also use arrays and copy values to another array if they are not already in it but that is usually the brute force way.

Comment: Bailey, that makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Admittedly, this problem would be easier if you could use external libraries, but if you are certain you cannot, it is still solvable.

I read the question incorrectly the first time. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50935662/remove-duplicates-from-an-unsorted-array/50935882) is a link to as similar question.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int removeDuplicates(int arr[], int n)
{
    int j = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j=0;j<i;j++){

            if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
                n--;
                for (int k=i; k<n; k++){
                    arr[k]=arr[k+1];
                }
                i--;     // you forgot to decrement i
            }
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

Comment: This answer is good but ill post alternatives in your comments for the op (: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/remove-duplicates-sorted-array/amp/

Comment: I may of read this wrong. If I selection sort the input, then remove the duplicates, I get an ordered output (i.e. 1 2 3 4 6 10 11 instead of 1 2 3 10 4 11 6).

Comment: @e3c you are correct, I read your question incorrectly and have updated my answer

Comment: you don't need to move all the elements every time you remove one